# Help me solve the invariant measure of $Q$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

My $Q$ matrix is given by:

\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda &0  &\lambda  &0  &0  &... \\ 
 \mu&-(\lambda+\mu) &0  &\lambda  &0  &... \\ 
 0&\mu  &-(\lambda+\mu)  &0  &\lambda  &... \\ 
 0&0  &\mu  &-(\lambda+\mu)  &0  &... \\ 
 ...& ... & 0 &\mu  &-(\lambda+\mu)  &... \\ 
 ...& ...&...  &...  &...  &... 
\end{bmatrix}

This is an infinite matrix, hopefully the pattern is clear.  The first row is unique, but each row after the second row is just the second row shifted over to the right by one more.  I'm trying to find its invariant measure, and I get the following equations:

$-\lambda\pi_1+\mu\pi_2=0$

$-(\lambda+\mu)\pi_2+\mu\pi_3=0$

$\lambda\pi_i-(\lambda+\mu)\pi_{i+2}+\mu\pi_{i+3}=0$ for $i=1,2,3,...$

But I'm finding these equations intractable, is there another way to find the invariant measure?  Or can someone help me resolve these equations.

Comment: You seem to be asking over and over the same question under different formulations. What happened to the specific indications previously provided to you?

Comment: @Did I only asked one other question related to this question, and that was about finding a way to solve the recurrence relation I derived from this $Q$ matrix, but the specific indications were useless and were essentially the method I had already considered (and explicitly mentioned).  Look back at the question if you don't believe me.

Comment: So... if I understand you correctly, the standard approach using the generating function of $\pi$ does not interest you? Since this is by far the best approach, I fail to see what would be an answer to this question. I will post the result of said standard approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stationary distribution $\pi$ exists if and only if the chain is positive recurrent. Since the drift at $i$, for every $i\geqslant1$, is $2\lambda-\mu$, this happens when $2\lambda\lt\mu$. Then, the standard approach to compute every $\pi_i$ is to look for the generating function $g(x)=\sum\limits_{i\geqslant1}\pi_ix^i$. The relations between the coefficients $\pi_i$ given above yield readily
$$
g(x)=\frac{\mu\pi_1x}{\mu-\lambda x-\lambda x^2}.
$$
The fact that $g(1)=1$ yields $\mu\pi_1=\mu-2\lambda$, hence
$$
g(x)=\frac{(\mu-2\lambda)x}{\mu-\lambda x-\lambda x^2}.
$$
To go further, one decomposes the denominator as
$$
\mu-\lambda x-\lambda x^2=\mu(1-\alpha x)(1+\beta x),
$$
for some suitable positive $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and one rewrites $g(x)$ as
$$
g(x)=\frac{\mu-2\lambda}{\mu(\alpha+\beta)}\left(\frac1{1-\alpha x}-\frac1{1+\beta x}\right),
$$
which yields finally, for every $i\geqslant1$,
$$
\pi_i=\frac{(\mu-2\lambda)(\alpha^i-(-1)^i\beta^i)}{\mu(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$